# Polymer Data Binding in Wordpress Page

Tags: wordpress, data-binding, binding, polymer

I've built a form using Polymer paper-input elements as a side project. Now I'm trying to integrate it into my Wordpress site.

So far I've been able to load all my bower_component dependencies in the functions.php using

```
function mytheme_enqueue_polymer() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'webcomponentsjs', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'mytheme_html_imports' );
function mytheme_html_imports() {
    ?>
    <link rel="import" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">

    <link rel="import" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/bower_components/iron-flex-layout/iron-flex-layout-classes.html">
    <link rel="import" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/bower_components/paper-card/paper-card.html">
    <link rel="import" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
    <link rel="import" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/bower_components/iron-form/iron-form.html">
    ...
    <?php } ?>
```

and my form code

```
<form is="iron-form" id="form6" method="get" action="http://httpbin.org/get">
  <paper-input name="fname" label="First Name" autocomplete="fname" value="{{fname}}"></paper-input>
  <input type="hidden" name="fname" value={{fname}}>
                ...
```

The paper-input elements appear correctly, but the data binding is not working correctly. I'm trying to bind the value={{}} attribute, but the page is displaying {{value}} literally in the input.

What do I need to do to get data binding working in a Wordpress page or post?

Answer (score 0):

What polymer version are you using? 1 ou 2? If its 2.0, the component code should be:

```html
<iron-form id="form6" on-iron-form-response="_onFormResponse" on-iron-form-error="_onFormError">
    <form method="get" action="http://httpbin.org/get">
        <paper-input name="fname" label="First Name" autocomplete="fname" value="{{fname}}"></paper-input>
        <input type="hidden" name="fname" value={{fname}}>
        ...
    </form>
</iron-form>
```